# SOLVED* The Graph Query Returns Page CSS Instead of Query of Token

Tags: jquery, axios, graphql, blockchain, uniswap

I am using the graphql module, the graph, to query the price of different tokens from different exchanges. Instead of returning the query results, which does work in the playground, it is returning what I think is the css of the playground page. It might be a problem with axios.

```
import axios, * as others from 'axios';

const main = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await axios.get(
            'http://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/aave/exchange/graphql',
            {
                query: `
flashLoans(first: 10, orderBy: timestamp, orderDirection: desc) {
    id
    reserve{
        name
        symbol
    }
    amount
    target
    timestamp
}
`
            }
        );
        console.dir(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
main();
```

The error it is returning is a thousand+ lines of code, starting with

```
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {
    date: 'Sat, 25 Jun 2022 03:20:23 GMT',
    'content-type': 'text/html',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    connection: 'close',
    'cf-ray': '720a91285d5419cf-EWR',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
    server: 'cloudflare'
  },
```

Anyone got any ideas?

***EDIT***

So I tried changeing the `axios.get` with `axios.post`, but that returned a 404 error, which I was able to fix by removing the `/graphql` in the http request. But the `axios.post` is still giving the same static content.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was able to fix this. I had accouple of small problems, but turns out my main problem was with the query itself. Here's the code if anyone wants.

```
import axios, * as others from 'axios';

const main = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await axios.post(
            'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/sushiswap/exchange',
            {
                query: `

                
query MyQuery{
    pair(id: "0xc3d03e4f041fd4cd388c549ee2a29a9e5075882f",
        block: {number:14914285}) {
        token0 {
          symbol
          id
          decimals
        }
        token1{
          symbol
          id
          decimals
        }
        
        token0Price
        token1Price
        volumeUSD
    
      }
      }

`
            }
        );
        console.log(result.data.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
main();
```